# Reformatting Array Objects Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[
  { apreciated_id: "123g1b1b23kbb3" },
  { apreciated_id: "asd567sad5a7sd" },
  { apreciated_id: "4hk3kjh234kjh4" }  
]
```

But I want it to look like this: ‍

```
["123g1b1b23kbb3", "asd567sad5a7sd", "4hk3kjh234kjh4"]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: `Array.prototype.map`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
const arr = [
  { apreciated_id: "123g1b1b23kbb3" },
  { apreciated_id: "asd567sad5a7sd" },
  { apreciated_id: "4hk3kjh234kjh4" }  
]

const result = arr.map(obj => obj.apreciated_id)
```

Map takes an array of length n of some type (in this case objects) and trasnforms it according to a function, to an array of length n of some other type (in this case strings)

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! and now I get it 

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to "transform" the array.

```js
let arr = [
    { apreciated_id: "123g1b1b23kbb3" },
    { apreciated_id: "asd567sad5a7sd" },
    { apreciated_id: "4hk3kjh234kjh4" }  
];

let res = arr.map(a => a.apreciated_id);

console.log(res);
```